# YAML Value Translation

Tags: ruby, yaml

So I want to have the following value for a YAML key:

```
\x1D\r\xAFK\xF3\x03\xE5Uj\x97\xD3B\xD5a'\e6\x93\xDD\x84\xCA\xC5\r\x90+\x12\xEA\x1E\xEC\xBE\x9C\x95`
```

However after setting it up like:

```
KEY: \x1D\r\xAFK\xF3\x03\xE5Uj\x97\xD3B\xD5a'\e6\x93\xDD\x84\xCA\xC5\r\x90+\x12\xEA\x1E\xEC\xBE\x9C\x95
```

I'm getting:

```
\\x1D\\r\\xAFK\\xF3\\x03\\xE5Uj\\x97\\xD3B\\xD5a'\\e6\\x93\\xDD\\x84\\xCA\\xC5\\r\\x90+\\x12\\xEA\\x1E\\xEC\\xBE\\x9C\\x95
```

after the YAML has been parsed.

Any thoughts on how I can retain the original string?

Comment: The best way to store binary data in YAML is to Base64-encode it and use the !!binary type. Do you have the ability to change the YAML or are you stuck with it? http://yaml.org/type/binary.html

Comment: Also, you'll see the double backslashes if you're inspecting the string, but that doesn't necessarily mean the string is being modified. Are you sure you're not just looking at the "printable" version?

Comment: @mwp is correct, it's not being modified, you're just seeing the escaped backslash in the string. I tried it with `YAML.load` and it appears to be working as you expect it to.